# Bottom Navigation and Fragment Tab Layout

Tags: android

I have a tab layout with 3 Fragments, I also have a BottomNavigation. So should I place BottomNavigation in an Activity for 3 Fragments or place a bottom navigation in each Fragment? Because I have a ListView in each Fragment so I think each Fragment should have one BottomNavigation for click event.

Comment: place bottomnavigation in your activity in which your fragments get call

Comment: Its better to keep BottomNavigation in activty only which is cantaining fragment, I think you are worry about the listView contained by fragments you can use fragment call back to handle visibility of BottomNavigation which scrolling of listView

Answer (score 0):

Just one BottomNavigation for all fragment.
You can easily use this [library](https://github.com/saeedsh92/bottomnavigation)     and then in YOUR_ACTIVITY_LAYOUT set it like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"
            android:name="com.ali.digikalaapp.Fragment_pager_one"
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


<com.ss.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigation
                android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                <com.ss.bottomnavigation.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tab_home"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:tab_text="Home"
                    app:tab_icon="@drawable/ic_home_white_24dp"
                    />
                <com.ss.bottomnavigation.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tab_images"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:tab_text="Images"
                    app:tab_icon="@drawable/ic_image_black_24dp"
                    />
                <com.ss.bottomnavigation.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/tab_camera"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:tab_text="Camera"
                    app:tab_icon="@drawable/ic_camera_white_24dp"
                    />
     </com.ss.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigation>


</RelativeLayout>
```

and if you have 3 Fragment , replace fragment like this in YOUR_ACTIVITY:

```
public class YOUR_ACTIVITY extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_ACTIVITY_LAYOUT);

            BottomNavigation bottomNavigation = (BottomNavigation) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

            bottomNavigation.setOnSelectedItemChangeListener(new OnSelectedItemChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSelectedItemChanged(int itemId) {
                    switch (itemId) {
                        case R.id.tab_home:
                            Fragment_Home home = new Fragment_Home();
                            FragmentManager fragment = getSupportFragmentManager();
                            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragment.beginTransaction();
                            transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, home);
                            break;
                        case R.id.tab_images:
                            Fragment_Image image = new Fragment_Image();
                            FragmentManager fragment = getSupportFragmentManager();
                            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragment.beginTransaction();
                            transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, image);
                            break;
                        case R.id.tab_camera:
                            Fragment_Camera camera = new Fragment_Camera();
                            FragmentManager fragment = getSupportFragmentManager();
                            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragment.beginTransaction();
                            transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, camera);
                            break;

                    }
                    transaction.commit();
                }
            }
        }
```

and here is one Fragment example :

```
public class Fragment_Home extends Fragment {

    public Fragment_Home() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    }

}
```

and here is fragment_home XML :

```
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".Fragment.Fragment_Home">


        <TextView
            android:text="Blank Fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```